# Checking server-side ad viewing (php)

Tags: java, php, android, server, admob

I have an application using php backend.  Let's say this is an app for cheating views on YouTube, or something else where points are very important.  I want to realize crediting points for viewing ads, but don’t know how to do it.  Of course, I can send a request to the server when an advertisement has been viewed,

```
   @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        if (sampleInterstitial != null) {
            //something code
        }
    }
```

but I'm afraid that a person rummaging in the code of my application will easily find which request I am sending and will be able to easily emulate my requests for building up points.  How can I avoid this?  For example, is it possible to somehow check from the server whether an ad was viewed?  **Thanks for answers)**

Answer (score 0):

First of all the client cannot check the server side code , **you do something like getting the ip address , time .. etc of anyone who views the ad** , and **inject it in a database or a file** , and in this way you can know how many people did and give it credits

- Your Php Ad page :

  ```
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // gets ip address
  $time = date_default_timezone_get(); // gets time
  // insert it in your file or database
  ```